# How to reduce size of massive title bar margin/padding in GNOME

Tags: gnome, 15.10, themes, gnome-tweak-tool

I recently did an upgrade from 15.04 to 15.10 and I don't believe the margins were nearly this ridiculous so I'm wondering if maybe something got reset/changed.

[image: Holy crap look at the size of that fatty?!]

As you can see, top GNOME bar is normal sized & the Firefox tab bar is also normal sized. Then smack dab in the middle is the monstrosity of a title bar that is roughly twice the size it ought to be.

I am using Numix for the GTK+ theme which never looked this bloated on any other machine I've used it on. I tried reducing the font size of the title bar but the problem is the margin/padding I'm guessing for which there doesn't appear to be any setting.

Comment: Your question is fine, as Gnome is a desktop environment available for Ubuntu. There's even an official derivate, Ubuntu GNOME.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create or modify `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

```
.header-bar.default-decoration { 
     padding-top: 3px; 
     padding-bottom: 3px; 
     border: none; 
     background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, 
                    shade(@theme_bg_color, 1.05), 
                    shade(@theme_bg_color, 0.99)); 
     box-shadow: inset 0 1px shade(@theme_bg_color, 1.4); 
} 

.header-bar.default-decoration .button.titlebutton { 
     padding-top: 2px; 
     padding-bottom: 2px; 
}
```

Then restart GNOME shell by Alt+F2 and `r` as command.

*Source*: http://jadelinux.com/fedoratips/titlebarheight.html

Comment: So after doing some unknown updates, I lost this file altogether. Any tips?

Comment: You can just create a new one. These are just override settings.

Comment: How can I make it permanent though? Recreating something repeatedly is not preferable. What is it ultimately overriding?

Comment: @kietnguen this didn't work for me. I'm using McOS theme, does the theme override my settings?

Answer (score 0):

Create or modify `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

```
.header-bar.default-decoration { 
     padding-top: 3px; 
     padding-bottom: 3px; 
     border: none;
}

.header-bar.default-decoration .button.titlebutton { 
     padding-top: 2px; 
     padding-bottom: 2px; 
}
```

Then restart GNOME shell by Alt+F2 and `r` as command.

---

*The extra bits omitted from this answer messed up the Numix theme.*